# How to get a dynamic node JSON value

Tags: javascript, json

```
   {       
        noteCount_xxx:
              {
              favorite:"favorite-border",
              id:"noteCount_xxx",
              note:"noteContent",
              title: "notetitle",
            }
    }
```

- This JSON data created at runtime,
- parent **`noteCount_xxx`** is dynamic
- I want to get value of that parent node
- the output will be

  {
    favorite: "favorite-border",
    id: "noteCount_xxx",
    note: "noteContent",
    title: "notetitle"
  }

> I am not able to get data from dynamic node, what is the best way to get that
>   data....?

Comment: How you create your json?

Comment: `var currentNote = '{ "' + noteCount + '" :{ "id": "' + noteCount + '","title":"' +  myApp.noteTitle + '","note":"' + myApp.noteText + '","favorite": "favorite-border"}}';             var person = JSON.parse(currentNote);`

Comment: @TusharAcharekar consider always putting important informations (such as `code`) in the question instead of in a comment. And when you get your solution, mind marking as answered. It'll be apreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to find out `nodeCount_xxx`'s value as:

```js
const yourJSON = {       
  noteCount_xxx:  {
    favorite:"favorite-border",
    id:"noteCount_xxx",
    note:"noteContent",
    title: "notetitle",
  }
}

const firstKey = Object.keys(yourJSON)[0]

console.log(yourJSON[firstKey])
```

Or in case you already know the value of `nodeCount_xxx`, simple access your object:

`yourJSON[noteCount]`

Comment: [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) would also work if you don't care about knowing the key

Comment: Thnaks `mersocarlin`, it's work fine and it will save my friday :)

Comment: @TusharAcharekar you're welcome. Should my answer be the correct one, would you mind to set it so we help others with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The object should be created dynamically instead in case the values are not properly escaped:

```js
var noteCount = "noteCount_" + 123

var parent = {
  favorite: "favorite-border",
  id: noteCount,
  note: "noteContent",
  title: "notetitle",
}

var person = { }
person[noteCount] = parent

console.log( parent )
console.log( person )
console.log( JSON.stringify( person ) )
```

---

If the JSON is from a separate process, the key value pairs can be accessed during the parsing:

```js
var parent, currentNote = '{"noteCount_123":{"favorite":"favorite-border","id":"noteCount_123","note":"noteContent","title":"notetitle"}}'

var person = JSON.parse(currentNote, function(key, value) { 
  return key ? parent = value : value })

console.log( parent )
console.log( person )
```